# Can I walk out of class?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If I am in a class where the teacher asks "[illegal questions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/1569)" (an "Ein Lomar"), what must I do?

- If I stay, I would now have those questions - very bedieved.
- If I close my ears I would have violated - Lishmoya Ozen.
- If I leave, I would now have violated the prohibition of "Chatzi Shiur" - which is biblicaly prohibited.

What should I do?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

Bang your head on the desk and become a shoteh, potur from aveiros!

Answer (score 2):

Of all of the concerns you raise, chatzi shiur is the most serious because it is d'oraisa as you correctly noted. Fortunately the solution to chatzi shiur is very simple. You must leave some time after the period is half finished. If your lecturer tends to go overtime, then the extra time is עולה לכאן ולכאן.